# How do I select and modify an NPC I can't see, via the console?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My dragonborn is in a bind. I'm doing the Thieves Guild quest line and am using Frostfall and iNeed.  This means I need to travel to Winterhold to prepare for a long, cold walk.  The problem is, be it fast travel or carriage, there are always Bandits with ranged weapons that spawn up the hill behind the Jarl's longhouse.  Since I'm also using a combat mod that makes combat lethal and introduces a wound system, and the shopkeeper (Birna) doesn't stay in her shop; she keeps taking an arrow up the backside and going down immediately.

This is a problem.  Her drunk brother died first due to their scripted event being in front of her shop the first time I was in Winterhold.   I didn't mind that because his quest is depressing and unrewarding, and what happened is his fault.  Birna, however, gives the Coral Claw as part of her quest and just resurrecting her doesn't change the flag in the game that says she is dead.  That affects other mods which handle the Halls of the Dead and graveyards,  as well as the game itself in some ways.   How can I set her as essential without zoning in close enough to see her and click on her with the console open?    Alternatively (and preferred), how can I toughen her up to at least tank a few arrows or lightning bolts?

Comment: I would recommend [Protect Your People](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/10297) mod, which sets NPCs to protected. Especially helpful if you are using OBIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the BaseID to alter the character even if she's nowhere in sight. Birna's BaseID is 0001C187 according to UESP, so you could open the console and type: `setessential 0001C187 1`.

You could also use the console to move Birna to you, using the RefID:
`prid 0001C18C` then `moveto player`.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer. Setting her to essential also makes her unable to be killed so that will toughen her up. You can also click on characters with the console open to get the BaseID if you need to do this in the future.

Comment: Anytime you make things lethal, you gotta do something about the NPCs.  They're damn stupid.  One dragon visit to a town and all the shopkeepers are dead...

Comment: Bethesda sort of missed the mark on setting some characters essential until their quests had been completed.  This answer worked for me, but with an adjustment.  The reason she kept dying is because her brother died during their scripted event when I first came to town.  She was stuck standing still.  I had to use StopQuest 000B2174 to get her to go inside and stop waiting on his corpse to talk to her.